# Viewstate seems to be hijacked inadvertently

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

we are using asp.net 2.x, we use session state stored in sql server, 2 web servers in loadbalance, iis6.

our issue is that in the last 3 months we have had 2 cases where some one using our enquiry form has seen someone else's info e.g. first name and last name. We are not populating the form from objects in session so I have come to the conclusion that the second user has somehow received the viewstate from the first user, after that user has tried to submit and got an error e.g. has posted view state and returned the the same page and the other user has requested that page at the same time (must have been on the same server I am guessing if it is a viewstate issue).

have any of you experienced this before? some questions mulling around in my head is how does the worker process know to retun view state to a unique request and how does it determine a unique request etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you use asp.net caching?

in the past, there have been some known issues with caching and mismatched sessions in load controlled environments.

I believe this article talks about it
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163577.aspx#S1

Comment: thanks for the article, we do use kernel mode cache or response.output.cache with vary by param, the enquiry form is not added to the output cache. The odd thing is that this is a viewstate issue,I supsect the article was talking about session objects though,The key thing here is that we use custom controls so viewstate might be handled slightly differently plus the fact that the article mentions:OutputCacheModule sometimes fails to strip Set-Cookie headers from the cached responses it passes to Http.sys.. and connecting users...this could be serving up the same html in the next response...

Comment: unless you override viewstate management in your custom controls, it should be pretty uniform with the rest of .net controls.. 
may be worth to investigate it more.. 
it also may be worth the effort to upgrade to the newer framework..

Comment: I am going to add enableKernelOutputCache="false" - our enquiry form sits under a differenct app domain than the rest of the site, lets see if this works...